# Scrapy [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some data from a website using scrapy. I am scraping the data using these lines of code:

`

```
def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    flat = FlatItem()
    for item in data["_embedded"]["estates"]:
        flat['flat'] = item['price']
        yield flat
```

`

and the FlatItem() contains a field like this:

`

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class FlatItem(Item):
    flat = Field()
```

`

Then, I am trying to paste it into postgresql database, with a command like this:

`

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    self.current.execute("""insert into flats(content, tags, author) values(%s)""", (
        item["flat"],
    ))

    self.connection.commit()
    return item
```

`

Unfortunatelly, when I'm trying to run the crawler, it gives me an exception like this:

```
2022-11-17 11:32:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'flat': 3299000}
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/XY/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 892, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
File "/Users/XY/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 285, in f
return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
File "/Users/XY/Library/CloudStorage/Creative/project/pipelines.py", line 29, in process_item
self.current.execute("""insert into flats(content, tags, author) values(%s)""", (
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

I`ve been trying to search for a solution for hours but unf nothing..

Any idea?

Trying to pass scraped data from scrapy to postgresql database, but expecting an error.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that one of your items has a `None` value and postgresql doesn't accept None as a value.

Try changing your pipeline `process_item()` to this:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print(item)
    print(item["flat"])
    if item["flat"]:
        self.current.execute(
           """insert into flats(content, tags, author) values(%s)""", 
           (item["flat"],)
         )
         self.connection.commit()
    return item
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly, that didn't help.. Still getting the same ERROR.. @Alexander

Comment: @CoderNoob  add the two print statements I included in my answer and tell me what they print.  They should print just before the code throws the error.

Comment: they print these lines (as expected): {'flat': 4801000}
4801000               @Alexander

Comment: And the type is of course int... @Alexander